# AJAX con PHP Buscador que consulta a BBDD

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy haciendo una especie de buscador, en el que mientras le pulsas a una tecla, se hace una petición AJAX para consultarlo en la BBDD. La cuestión es que no se todavía mucho de AJAX y no me funciona. De momento estoy probando con un texto cualquiera en vez de consultarlo a la base de datos.

HTML:

```
<input placeholder="Buscar..." id="buscador" type="text">
<p class="resultados"></p>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#buscador').on('keypress', () => {
    let busqueda = $('#buscador').val();  

    // Ajax para recibir los 'posts'
    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
data: busqueda,

        url: 'ajax/indexAjax.php',
        success: function(respuesta) {
          $('.resultados').html(respuesta);
       }
    });

    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $busqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];
    $data = "";
    if(isset($busqueda)){
        $data = $busqueda;
    }else{
        $data = "No existe";
    }

    return $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estoy viendo en tu **ajax** es que en el atributo **data** no le estas asignando un indice para pasarlo al **php**, debería de quedar así:

```
$('#buscador').on('keypress', () => {
    let busqueda = $('#buscador').val();  

    // Ajax para recibir los 'posts'
    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        data: {busqueda:busqueda},
        url: 'ajax/indexAjax.php',
        error: function (request, status, error) {
          alert(request.responseText);
        },
        success: function(respuesta) {
          $('.resultados').html(respuesta);
       }
    });

  });
```

Te agregue también un manejador de errores para que te guíes si te da algún error como un 404.

Con respecto al **PHP** deberías de cambiar el **return** por un **echo** ya que el **JS** no puede capturar un **return** desde el **php** pero si un **echo**, deberia de quedar así:

```
<?php
    $busqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];
    $data = "";
    if(isset($busqueda)){
        $data = $busqueda;
    }else{
        $data = "No existe";
    }

    echo $data;
?>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por contestar! Sigue sin funcionarme... El archivo PHP está bien?

Comment: Si ese es el php el cual el ajax esta llamando no tienes que darl un return sino un echo, prueba y me dices

Comment: Con un echo sí me funciona

Comment: Perfecto, ya edite mi respuesta si mi respuesta te ayudo me puedes colocar la respuesta como correcta por favor, gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Pero imagíante que le quiero pasar un objeto. Con un echo no puedo

Comment: al ajax tienes que agregarle algo como `dataType: "json"`, y en el php le das un `echo json_encode($_POST);` en el json_encode solo van arrays

Comment: Buenas, que paso por que me quitaste la respuesta como correcta?

Comment: Uy perdón, no se lo que ha pasado jajaja. Ahora la pongo como correcta, lo siento.

Comment: Muchas gracias!